# Use of Access Log sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, performance-testing

I tried to use "access log sampler" for two websites. for first one I get the logs but for 2nd logs were not generated.

```
1st one having SSH/SSL certificated
2nd site having expired SSL.
```

May I know what is the reason for not getting the logs for the 2nd website?

Comment: What are the URL's?

Answer (score 1):

Access Log Sampler is used to generated logs in JMeter

Create a `.txt` file where you saved your test plan and In access sampler, there is an option to browse this file

```
Log file: "" Provide the path of .txt file here and save your test plan
Run your script and check the log file.
```

> Note: Server Port is required to use "Access Log sampler and your site should be SSL certified"

Answer (score 1):

Can you show 1st line of log for website 1 and website 2. It might be the case that you need to "prepare" the log so JMeter could "consume" it.

See [How to use Access Log Sampler to Generate Traffic with JMeter?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15851/use-of-access-log-sampler-in-jmeter) article for example of access log conversion.

Comment: Hi Dmitri,
Log is not generated for 2nd website. 
1448979394473,2261,806 /,200,OK,Thread Group 1-2,text,true,20682,10,10,2029 1st line of log for 1st website

Comment: If there is no log - you won't be able to use Access Log Sampler